# afnetworking json response with unicode - only some work

Tags: ios, json, http, unicode, afnetworking-2

I am using AFNetworking 2 to get JSON from my server which looks like this:

```
{"comment": "<some string>"}
```

this works perfectly fine when i have regular text or regular symbols.

it even works with emojis - so when my comment is \uD83D\uDE04 it works perfectly and i see the smiley

```
{"commentText":"\uD83D\uDE04"} (smiley http://www.charbase.com/1f604-unicode-smiling-face-with-open-mouth-and-smiling-eyes)
```

now if i do other letters like - ä - it suddenly doesn't work any more

```
{"commentText":"\u00E4"} (ä - http://www.charbase.com/00e4-unicode-latin-small-letter-a-with-diaeresis)
```

it actually doesnt throw an error but the json returned is nil

any help would be great!

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out that instead of using encoding NSUTF8StringEncoding i had to use NSASCIIStringEncoding and everything works perfect now